# how to safely unwrap my coredata objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

hey I have these coredata objects in a switch statements that I'm trying to safely unwrap, but I have no idea how to do it in this scenario.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let msg : Mesages = fetchedResultsControler.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Mesages
    switch (msg.fromID!) {

    case(friend!.id!) : let messageData = JSQMessage(senderId: friend!.id!, displayName: friend!.id!, text: msg.text)
    return messageData

    default :
        let messageData = JSQMessage(senderId: userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String, displayName: userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String, text: msg.text)
    return messageData
    }
}
```

I need to unwrap safely `msg.fromID!` and `friend!.id!`

```
var friend: Friend?
extension Friend {
@NSManaged var id: String?
}

extension Mesages {
@NSManaged var fromID: String?
@NSManaged var text: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (friend?.id) != nil {
        switch (msg.fromID) {
        case(friend!.id!)? :
            _ = friend!.id
        default :
            _ = "FBid"
        }
    }
```

For the switch part, you can match by `case value?` -> This resolves to true if msg.fromID is not an optional.
For friend.id, I guess you will probably have to check for it outside the switch. Maybe somebody else can give you a better solution for friend.id.